# Clamping camera forward and backward vector in Unity3D

Tags: unity, camera

My perspective camera is rotated on the x axis. I've implemented a zoom with the scroll wheel and it works great.

I'm trying to limit the zoom, however. My solution right now is to take the relative scale of the `transform.forward` y and z components and clamp the y and z position of the camera by using `Mathf.Clamp` and multiplying the `minZoom` and `maxZoom` floats by the corresponding `transform.forward` component. It works well, except it limits the y axis, so when I translate around I can't go below a given y due to my clamp with is ideally meant to affect the zoom only.

Is there a way to clamp the forward and backward movement of the camera? I've been looking everywhere but can't find a thing.

Thanks.

**Code**

```
public class ClickManager : MonoBehaviour

{
    public float dragSpeed = 2;
    public float minZoom = 0.5f;
    public float maxZoom = 5.0f;

    private Vector3 dragOrigin;

    private float lerpPercentBack = 0; // value between 0 and 1 representing percentage of lerp
    private float lerpPercentForward = 0;
    private bool isLerpingBack = false;
    private bool isLerpingForward = false;



    void Update()
    {
        float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            dragOrigin = Input.mousePosition;
            return;
        }

        if (scroll > 0)
        {
            isLerpingForward = true;
            lerpPercentForward = 0;
        }
        if (scroll < 0)
        {
            isLerpingBack = true;
            lerpPercentBack = 0;
        }



        if (isLerpingBack)
        {
            scrollLerperBack();
            lerpPercentBack += 0.05f;

            if (lerpPercentBack >= 1.0f)
            {
                lerpPercentBack = 0;
                isLerpingBack = false;
            }
        }


        if (isLerpingForward)
        {

            scrollLerperForward();
            lerpPercentForward += 0.05f;

            if (lerpPercentForward >= 1.0f)
            {
                lerpPercentForward = 0;
                isLerpingForward = false;
            }
        }

        //Debug.Log(lerpPercent);

        /*if (!Input.GetMouseButton(1)) return;

        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition - dragOrigin);
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(pos.x * dragSpeed, pos.y * dragSpeed, 0);

        transform.Translate(move, Space.World);

        Debug.Log(scroll);*/


    }


    void scrollLerperBack()
    {
        transform.position -= Vector3.Lerp(transform.forward, Vector3.zero, lerpPercentBack);
    }


    void scrollLerperForward()
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.Lerp(transform.forward, Vector3.zero, lerpPercentForward);
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;

        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, minZoom * transform.forward.y,
            maxZoom * transform.forward.y);
        pos.z = Mathf.Clamp(pos.z, minZoom * transform.forward.z, 
            maxZoom * transform.forward.z);
        transform.localPosition = pos;
    }

}
```

Comment: you can fix your problem by [MouseOrbitZoom](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MouseOrbitZoom),[MouseOrbitInfiteRotateZoom](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MouseOrbitInfiteRotateZoom),[MouseOrbitImproved](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MouseOrbitImproved),.......[all controllers](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Scripts/Controllers)

Answer (score 1):

`scroll` value resets when it's not scrolling. For one time scrolling the value turns `+/- 0.1f`. For multiple time scrolling at a time it changes `+/- 0.1f` on the current `scroll` value. Else it resets to **Zero** on next frame. That's why `scrollCount` will be used as scroll counter.

Two new variables:

```
private float scrollCount = 0f; //scroll count is related to max zoom

[SerializeField]
private float maxZoomLevel = 0.2f; //so zoom levels are -0.2f, -0.1f, 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.2f
```

Changes in `Update()` which will replace your `if (scroll > 0)` and `if (scroll < 0)` blocks of code.

```
    if ((Mathf.Abs(scroll) == 0.1f && //Checking for one time scrolls only
             scrollCount < maxZoomLevel + 0.1f && scrollCount > -maxZoomLevel - 0.1f)) //Margins on max and min zoom level
    {
        if (scroll == 0.1f && scrollCount < maxZoomLevel) //Zoom In
        {
            scrollCount += 0.1f;

            isLerpingForward = true;
            lerpPercentForward = 0;

            isLerpingBack = false;
            lerpPercentBack = 0;
        }

        if (scroll == -0.1f && scrollCount > -maxZoomLevel) //Zoom Out
        {
            scrollCount -= 0.1f;

            isLerpingForward = false;
            lerpPercentForward = 0;

            isLerpingBack = true;
            lerpPercentBack = 0;
        }
    }
```

Get rid of your `FixedUpdate()` statements and enable the code at the end of `Update()` regarding `Vector3 pos` and `Vector3 move`.

There is another solution for Zoom. You may use `Camera.main.fieldOfView` for perspective camera. Field of view is by default `60f`. Less than `60f` will zoom in and greater than `60f` will zoom out. For little amount of zoom changing field of view is harmless.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting some problems with the zoom not properly maintaining its minimum and maximum. I think I'll use field of view, it seems a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//Filename: maxCamera.cs
//
// original: http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=MouseOrbitZoom
//
// --01-18-2010 - create temporary target, if none supplied at start

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/3dsMax Camera Style")]
public class maxCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
        public Transform target;
        public Vector3 targetOffset;
        public float distance = 5.0f;
        public float maxDistance = 20;
        public float minDistance = .6f;
        public float xSpeed = 200.0f;
        public float ySpeed = 200.0f;
        public int yMinLimit = -80;
        public int yMaxLimit = 80;
        public int zoomRate = 40;
        public float panSpeed = 0.3f;
        public float zoomDampening = 5.0f;

        private float xDeg = 0.0f;
        private float yDeg = 0.0f;
        private float currentDistance;
        private float desiredDistance;
        private Quaternion currentRotation;
        private Quaternion desiredRotation;
        private Quaternion rotation;
        private Vector3 position;

        void Start() { Init(); }
        void OnEnable() { Init(); }

        public void Init()
        {
            //If there is no target, create a temporary target at 'distance' from the cameras current viewpoint
            if (!target)
            {
                GameObject go = new GameObject("Cam Target");
                go.transform.position = transform.position + (transform.forward * distance);
                target = go.transform;
            }

            distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
            currentDistance = distance;
            desiredDistance = distance;

            //be sure to grab the current rotations as starting points.
            position = transform.position;
            rotation = transform.rotation;
            currentRotation = transform.rotation;
            desiredRotation = transform.rotation;

            xDeg = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.right, transform.right );
            yDeg = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, transform.up );
        }

        /*
     * Camera logic on LateUpdate to only update after all character movement logic has been handled. 
     */
        void LateUpdate()
        {
            // If Control and Alt and Middle button? ZOOM!
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(2) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
            {
                desiredDistance -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * zoomRate*0.125f * Mathf.Abs(desiredDistance);
            }
            // If middle mouse and left alt are selected? ORBIT
            else if (Input.GetMouseButton(2) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt))
            {
                xDeg += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * 0.02f;
                yDeg -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

                ////////OrbitAngle

                //Clamp the vertical axis for the orbit
                yDeg = ClampAngle(yDeg, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
                // set camera rotation 
                desiredRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yDeg, xDeg, 0);
                currentRotation = transform.rotation;

                rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRotation, desiredRotation, Time.deltaTime * zoomDampening);
                transform.rotation = rotation;
            }
            // otherwise if middle mouse is selected, we pan by way of transforming the target in screenspace
            else if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
            {
                //grab the rotation of the camera so we can move in a psuedo local XY space
                target.rotation = transform.rotation;
                target.Translate(Vector3.right * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * panSpeed);
                target.Translate(transform.up * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * panSpeed, Space.World);
            }

            ////////Orbit Position

            // affect the desired Zoom distance if we roll the scrollwheel
            desiredDistance -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * Time.deltaTime * zoomRate * Mathf.Abs(desiredDistance);
            //clamp the zoom min/max
            desiredDistance = Mathf.Clamp(desiredDistance, minDistance, maxDistance);
            // For smoothing of the zoom, lerp distance
            currentDistance = Mathf.Lerp(currentDistance, desiredDistance, Time.deltaTime * zoomDampening);

            // calculate position based on the new currentDistance 
            position = target.position - (rotation * Vector3.forward * currentDistance + targetOffset);
            transform.position = position;
        }

        private static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
        {
            if (angle < -360)
                angle += 360;
            if (angle > 360)
                angle -= 360;
            return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}
```